# Pre-defined attributes

Tags: css

I have this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/XjeCf/1/ that works like I want and this one : http://jsfiddle.net/XjeCf/ that doesn't.

What should I add to the tag `triangle` so that it acts like the div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add:

```
display: block;
```

this might differ by browser, though, as their default stylesheets vary (I'm testing in Chrome). You should use the inspector/Firebug/etc. to see what styles are getting applied by the browser.

Finally, you should strongly reconsider using custom tags in HTML, as it defeats the purpose of having a specification.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add `display:block;`.

Answer (score 1):

You should add

```
display:block;
```

to your triangle css